# Running an APK made for Android Kitkat with HTTP Apache client in an Android Marshmallow device

Tags: java, android, http, android-6.0-marshmallow, apache-httpclient-4.x

I built an app for Android KitKat (4.4) that uses the following Apache classes:

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

I read in Android's docs that they removed compatibility with Apache HTTP Client but I would like to know what that means for apps made for previous versions. So what happens if I run my app in an Android Marshmallow (6.0) device? What issues may I face?

As a side note, I already installed my app in a device with Android 6.0 and I am facing issues regarding HTTP requests made to my server, but since I am not sure what compatibility issues may arise, I can only assume (but not be sure) that it could be related.

The issue is the following:

1. When I turn on the device and my app is started by BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, the HTTP requests made by my app to my server are successful.
2. After what in my opinion can only be a random time, all the requests return the following error:

```
11-29 10:11:50.690 22608 22770 W System.err: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.56.12.131:80 timed out
11-29 10:11:50.691 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:126)
11-29 10:11:50.691 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
11-29 10:11:50.691 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
11-29 10:11:50.692 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
11-29 10:11:50.692 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
11-29 10:11:50.692 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
11-29 10:11:50.692 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
11-29 10:11:50.692 22608 22770 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at com.colaboracionvirtual.provisioningmanager.services.SynchronizationService$ServiceCall.doInBackground(SynchronizationService.java:221)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at com.colaboracionvirtual.provisioningmanager.services.SynchronizationService$ServiceCall.doInBackground(SynchronizationService.java:1)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-29 10:11:50.693 22608 22770 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

*Note: 10.56.12.131:80 is the IP address and port of my Web server*

Even after stopping my app with `am force-stop my.app` and then restarting it with `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n my.app/.receivers.BootReceiver`, all HTTP requests to my server keep throwing that timeout error.

To debug the issue I played arround with netstat command and the results were the following:

1. When the HTTP requests are working properly, I get the following output from netstat:

```
nobody@rk312x:/ # netstat -tn | grep 10.56.12.131:80
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:48752 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  SYN_SENT
```

1. When the HTTP requests are throwing timeout error, I get the following output from netstat:

```
nobody@rk312x:/ # netstat -tn | grep :80
tcp        1      0 192.168.89.2:53676      10.56.12.131:80         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:37081 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:38081 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:40148 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:35892 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:45924 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:42781 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:37544 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:58794 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:56087 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:40208 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:58789 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:44985 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:50971 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.89.2:49985 ::ffff:10.56.12.131:80  CLOSE_WAIT
```

The most strange thing is that via ADB I make a request to the server using `busybox wget http://10.56.12.131/api/service/` and the result is gotten without any issues.

FYI: my app uses the libraries `httpcore-4.3.2.jar`, `httpmime-4.3.1.jar` and `commons-io-2.4.jar`.

Note: this question is about installing an APK compiled for Android Kitkat in and Android 6.0, not about recompiling it for Android 6.0 and then installing it in in that same OS.

Comment: Have you added the Apache Legacy library to your build.grade, as per https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: Retracted Redacted, this question is about installing an APK compiled for Android 4.4, not for recompiling it for Android 6.0.

Comment: To clarify, you are targetting 4.4? Or is 4.4 your minimum SDK version?

Comment: The manifest of the already compiled APK uses: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`